# How can I redirect url on my my host?

Tags: asp.net, web, redirect

I want to redirect url to my site.
I mean I have this domain.

```
  www.samplesite.com
```

and I have this site : **www.samplesite.com/test/index.aspx**
but I want to enter **www.samplesite.com** and goes to my site.
How can I do that?

I use dot net ,4.5 framework.

Comment: You need to tell more about the technology involved. Some solutions may be server side, others client side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using asp.net web forms you can create a Default.aspx page, in the `Page_Load` method in the `Default.aspx.cs` file call this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/test/index.html");
}
```

Comment: Can I write it notepad? or I need to write it on visual studio and publish again my site

Comment: @user3086226: you need to rebuild, so use Visual Studio.